# Fail to compile opencv with arm-linux-g++ (cross compilation)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cross-compiling

This is my first time asking on stackoverflow.I'll show you the problem as unambiguous as I can.

This library works fine on x86 computer,but when it comes to cross compilation(I installed this library in 2 different directories so they both exist), it just can't pass the compilation, saying things like

```
"undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'"
```

I know it may means I failed to reference the libraries, but on x86 linux, just typing

```
`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

would be fine. Ah I have tried several ways but it just failed!

Currently I can't post images but I'll show you the library files.

```
libopencv_calib3d.so
libopencv_contrib.so
libopencv_core.so
libopencv_features2d.so
libopencv_flann.so
libopencv_gpu.so
libopencv_highgui.so
libopencv_imgproc.so
libopencv_legacy.so
libopencv_ml.so
libopencv_nonfree.so
libopencv_objdetect.so
libopencv_photo.so
libopencv_stitching.so
libopencv_superres.so
libopencv_ts.so
libopencv_video.so
libopencv_videostab.so
```

Ah how to reference the libraries? I've tried lots of popular google results but I just failed, so I need your help, thank you so much!

Comment: SO, using `nm` on your x86-system, can you locate where that name is declared? Then compare the same file on ARM?

Answer (score 0):

In the Makefile (which is where I presume `pkg-config --libs opencv` is), replace `pkg-config --libs opencv` with

```
-L<directory where the ARM .so files are> -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib ...
```

You may have to change the order of the -l options depending on which of the libraries refer to other libraries. A library that refers to a symbol in another library should preceed it on the command line because libraries are searched in order.